# React native Unable to resolve module 'module://react-native-screens.js

Tags: react-native

i got one very short help i hope
When i try to run my App on snak.expo.io I receive the following error message:

Unable to resolve module 'module://react-native-screens.js

Who can help me on this?
I've tried to add an explicit import for this 3 modules
react-native-gesture-handler ,react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens

but still same error message

Any Idea?

Comment: can you give a link to you snack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same exact issue as you, here's the forum that I've been following with the right solution https://forums.expo.io/t/unable-to-resolve-module-module-expo-font-js/34233/5. Turns out you can just drop the version of Snack to 35.0.0 and it works!

Look for the bottom right on the snack to change the version. Hope that helps!

Edit: Added the solution when it was resolved

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your tip howard

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you